# Notation For Delta Distribution

Tags: notation, dirac-delta

I've encountered two different notations for the delta distribution:
$$\delta(x,y)$$
and
$$\delta(x-y)$$
What is the difference between these two notations. Do they depend on context or should I prefer one over the other?

Comment: The first one is not sufficiently standard for me to even know the intended meaning. The second one is quite standard (if the variable of integration is $x$, then this can be understood as a point mass of $1$ at $y$).

Comment: If the domain / space isn't additive, then $x-y$ makes no sense. But usually one writes $\delta_y$ if the mass is centered at $y$.

Answer (score 2):

The first describes a delta function acting at the **origin**.

[image: point]

The second describes a delta function acting along the **line $x=y$**:

[image: line]

Answer (score 0):

The first notation is more convenient when working in high dimensions, since it naturally generalizes to $n$ dimensions:  e.g., $\delta (x,y,z,w, ...)$.  You can do this with the second notation $\delta(x) \delta(y), ...$

Certain software (e.g., *Mathematica*) supports both usages.

Comment: Thanks for your help with the Mathematica graphics.